# linux - openvpn: active connections not showing

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn

good day all

My openvpn server uses NTP / port 123 UDP, and while I am connected to the vpn and having an active data stream through it, I am not able to detect my IP on the server side

I only see my ssh session over 22, but that is about that

```
netstat -tu

Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 {server_ip}:57991 {remote_ip}.ip.:http CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 {server_ip}:ssh {partner_ip}:61761 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0     36 {server_ip}:ssh {my_ip}:60992 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 {ipv6_ip} 2601:{ipv6_ip}:53558 TIME_WAIT
```

no mention is made of a port 123, the only feedback I got from port 123 udp / ntp was

```
netstat -a

...
udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:* 
...
```

and

```
ss -a | grep 123
```

has no result, is this a security function of openvpn to hide all IP's associated? How am I able to view my IP as a openvpn client?

**UPDATE**

running

```
netstat -antup | grep 123
```

responds with

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           410/openvpn
```

I have come across posts mentioning using openvpn-status.log, I am currently coding a small script to show only associated IP's, this status log updates in 1 minute intervals, its the closest I have come to viewing "active" connections!

Answer (score 0):

UPD is a connectionless protocol therefore it does not show as `connected`

Comment: Try `netstat -antup`

Comment: check update of new info

Comment: as you can see `udp:123` is being used by `openvpn`, that is the sum extent to which you can use netstat to show your connection because UDP is a connectionless protocol.

Answer (score 0):

TO find your VPN client IP you can use the OpenVPN log file (server or client).  Also, as you are logged in to ssh on the server `netstat -antup` (without grep) will show your client IP connected to ssh port.